# Apply noise on non zero elements of data frame

Tags: pandas

I am a bit struggling with this one.

I have a dataframe, and I want to apply gaussian noise only on the non zero elements of the data frame. A silly way to do this is :

```
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[1]):
        if df.iat[i,j] != 0:
            df.iat[i,j] += np.random.normal(mu,sigma)
```

Noise must be different for each element, we do not add the same value each time.

And I would be happy if only this worked. Actually for some reason it does not. Instead, I got this :

[before noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyqkx.png)

[after noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgu1V.png)

As you can see on the image, for columns  A and C it is working well, but not for the others. What is weird is that there is still a change (+/- 1, so far from what one would except of a gaussian noise...)

I tried to see if this was some decimals problem with df.round() but nothing came up.

So I am looking for another way to apply my noise mostly rather than to solve this weird problem. Thank you by advance.

Comment: Before you proceed: 1st: Is Pandas necessary or is numpy the better choice? 2nd and more important: Use vectorization. There are really rare cases where a nested for loop is the way to go in pandas

Comment: jezrael solved my problem. For the 2nd remark, I am well aware of the benefits of vectorization and first thing I tried was to extract the non zero values index of the data frame instead of looping over the df... But got unlucky ! Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can generate array with same size as orignal `DataFrame` and then add values by condition with [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
np.random.seed(234)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5,5)))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  4  1  1  3
1  3  0  3  3  2
2  0  2  4  1  3
3  4  0  3  0  2
4  3  1  3  3  1

mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
a = np.random.normal(mu,sigma, size=df.shape)
print (a)
[[ 0.10452115 -0.01051424 -0.13329652 -0.06376671  0.07245456]
 [-0.21753186  0.05700441  0.03595196 -0.08154859  0.0076684 ]
 [ 0.08368405  0.10390984  0.04692948  0.09711873 -0.06820933]
 [-0.07229613  0.03954906 -0.06136678 -0.02328597 -0.22123564]
 [-0.04316055  0.05945377  0.13736261  0.07895045  0.03714287]]

df = df.where(df == 0, df.add(a))
print (df)
           0         1         2         3         4
0  0.000000  3.989486  0.866703  0.936233  3.072455
1  2.782468  0.000000  3.035952  2.918451  2.007668
2  0.000000  2.103910  4.046929  1.097119  2.931791
3  3.927704  0.000000  2.938633  0.000000  1.778764
4  2.956839  1.059454  3.137363  3.078950  1.037143
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks a lot I tried many ways for a good hour. Solved :)